# Remote VPN User - Domain Credentials

Tags: windows-7, vpn, offline-files, windows-sbs-2011

Morning,

We have a client who uses a Windows 7 laptop and connects remotely to an SBS2011 network via VPN that terminates at a Watchguard device.

This is a recent upgrade, the server was SBS2003 and the clients laptop was XP but the Watchguard has remained the same.

The issue is the clients laptop, which is a member of the domain, appears to lose it's connection every now and again. That is to say not his actual internet connection nor the VPN but the server seems to forget he's actually connected and he's prompted for a password when trying to access Outlook and when accessing shares.

I've created a new VPN account on the Watchguard so that the VPN U/N and P/W is now the same between the two accounts in case that was causing an issue.

I've also increased the time that Offline Files checks for to see if it's connected from 5 minutes to three hours and the timeout period on the Watchguard for the VPN is set to 23 hours.

DNS and GW settings have been checked both on the VPN and LAN  / WLAN.

I'm missing something but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of disconnection usually occurs because the VPN connection's Default Gateway for routing is used instead of the real LAN connection's Default Gateway. In Network places go to the VPN's properties,

**Networking > IP V4 Properties > Advanced > Use default gateway for remote networks**

Uncheck that option and it wont get disconnected like it happens now.